# How to copy a dataset(ps or pds) from MVS to PC using JCL

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I want to copy a mvs file to my PC.. I have tried with the below code.

```
//JOBNAME JOB NOTIFY=&SYSUID,CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=X,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),  
 //         REGION=0M                                              
 //STEP01   EXEC PGM=FTP                                                                    
 //OUTPUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                            
 //SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                            
 //INPUT    DD *                                                   
 MVS IP ADDRESS                                                    
 USER.ID(MVS)                                                           
 PASSWORD                                                           
 PUT 'USERID.NEW1.TXT' C:\MYPATH\DATA.TXT               
 QUIT                                                              
 /*
```

spool output shows

**'Invalid data set name "c:\mypath\data.txt". Use MVS Dsname conventions.'**

But it is working fine with MVS to MVS dataset but not with PC.
Can anyone suggest me what has to be done further.

Comment: Your job is connecting to an MVS box not a PC. Do you have an FTP server running on your Windows PC? I very much doubt it.  You can start and FTP server on Windows using IIS but almost nobody does that because it's considered a security risk.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have ftp server on my PC. I have searched all the sites and this was the syntax mentioned..

Comment: you would be better off just connecting to the FTP using either an FTP client or even a windows cmd prompt.

Comment: You have your senses reversed; all the control cards, except for the PUT, are all for sending to z/OS. If you do want to do this, I recommend as well that you use CD and LCD to navigate and then use just the file names in the PUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do have an FTP server running on your PC, or a Windows server then it's simple to FTP using batch. Although the syntax you specified using a drive like C:\path\file is not supported. FTP commands and directory structures are similar Unix. When you configured the FTP server you would have specified a root directory (folder) that clients can access. You can't just access the entire Windows file system.

This JCL will work.

```
//FTPSTEP  EXEC PGM=FTP,REGION=0M        
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*                  
//INPUT    DD  *                         
*windows-ip-address*                     
*windows-username windows-password*    
put 'USERID.NEW1.TXT' new1.txt           
quit
```

Comment: Are you sure you have an FTP server running on Windows? Post your JCL and the error.

Comment: Yes, i m sure about that..I used the same code which you have shared..It was not a error..could not connect **..Connection to server interrupted or timed out. Initial connection..**

Comment: You need to make sure your Windows firewall settings are correct for the FTP server https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-ftp-server-windows-10.